# Extract portion of filename C#

Tags: c#

Hey, I have filenames like this: R303717COMP_148A2075_20100520_19230.txt 
(the R number and the other numbers vary, but same format)

I would like to extract the 148A2075  and  20100520 separately into variables for use inserting in a column of my sqlite db.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method. Example:

```
string name = "R303717COMP_148A2075_20100520_19230.txt";
string[] tokens = name.Split('_');

// tokens[1] == "148A2075"
// tokens[2] == "20100520"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string filename = "R303717COMP_148A2075_20100520_19230.txt";

string[] chunks = filename.Split('_');

Console.Writeline(chunks[1]); // this prints 148A2075 

Console.Writeline(chunks[2]); // this prints 20100520
```